# Как сделать TabLayout без адаптера

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Нужно сделать 2 таба, только контент во вкладках должен заполняться не адаптером, а просто набором нескольких вьюшек. например есть 2 LinearLayout с готовым набором View, нужно разместить их в содержимом табов. возможно ли такое? или обязательно городить фрагменты, адаптер и еще кучу кода? я бы сделал это с TabHost, но у него нету свайпа

Comment: Используйте `ViewPager`. Но, без адаптера не обойтись

Comment: но ведь адаптер предполагает однотипное содержимое, а мне надо просто как бы 2 разные страницы разместить в табах+свайп

Comment: Адаптер ничего такого не предполагает. Вы сами решаете какое содержимое показывать. Можете сделать простой выбор: если position == 0 показать вью для первой страницы, если 1, то для второй.